# Circuitikz: Invert amp

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm trying to use the code `invert` in `circuitikz`, however I'm getting an error with it, other bipoles work well. How can I invert/ flip it?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/amp/width=0.9}
\draw (0,0) to[amp,t=LNA,l_=$F{=}0.9\,$dB,o-o] ++(3,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: showed image is not produced with provided mwe. sorry, but from your question is not clear (to me), what you like to obtain. reversed direction of amplifier?

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I use `invert` like in your example I get the error `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/invert' and
I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` This happens on both my own setup and online platforms like overleaf.

Comment: apparently overleaf has old installation of the `circuitikz` package. with the recent version the `miktex` package it works. function `invert` is documented in the package documentation (version 0.8.3 (2017/05/28) ) on page 43 in the section *5.8 Mirroring and Inverting*. try to upgrade your installation of `latex`.

Comment: I changed the package locally now it works on my machine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your mwe produce the following figure:

[image]

if you like to to obtain the following figure

[image]

than try the following:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
%\ctikzset{bipoles/amp/width=0.9}
\draw (0,0) to[amp, invert,                 % <---
                    mirror,                 % <---
                    t=\rotatebox{180}{LNA}, % <---
                    l_=$F{=}0.9\,$dB,o-o] ++(3,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```